# Generate an image of a view, at a specific size?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view that shows some information to the user. Currently, the user can tap a share button to share an image of the view, so they can easily post the information to Twitter, or text it to a friend. But of course, the view is laid out using AutoLayout and can be displayed at different sizes depending on the device. The image output looks nice, but I'd like to make the app save this image at a standard size regardless of the interface resolution or orientation.

What's the best way of generating an image like this at a specified size? Is there an easy way, or will I have to generate an image in a totally different way? Here's the code for how I'm currently doing this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [snapshot], applicationActivities: nil)

if let popover = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
    popover.barButtonItem = shareButton
}

presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect the width and height constraints to your code. Temporarily change them:

```
width.constant = 1234
height.constant = 1234
```

Then put them back.